# Issues resetting the MySQL password on an Amazon EC2 'Amazon Linux' instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2

Been fighting with resetting the `root` password for MySQL on an Amazon Linux hosted on EC2. Version:

> mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.42, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1

When installing, I decided it would be smart to change the root password to something secure! Yay! Security! Except it won’t let me log in with that password now, so I’m trying to reset it.

I followed [the instructions here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/resetting-permissions.html), but it’s not working. I thought it might be permissions on the init file, but they're set to `rwxrwxrwt` so probably not, but maybe? Not even sure what log files to check to see where it's going wrong either.

So, how can I successfully reset the MySQL password on EC2 Amazon Linux? Is the set of instructions linked to supposed to work, or does Amazon do something differently?

Also I [asked this on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/717787/resetting-mysql-password-on-ec2-amazon-linux), but it wasn’t “clear” what I was asking. I’d say this is rather off topic for here too, but…

Comment: It is Amazon Linux - an EC2 instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspecting the output from running `mysqld_safe`, it kindly indicates that it's logging to `/var/log/mysqld`. The notable part it says:

> `150830  6:32:18 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: File '/home/ec2-user/mysql-init' not found (Errcode: 2)`

Turns out that root can't access that location. Moved the file to `/tmp/mysql-init` and then the password reset worked.

Comment: Yeah - that's exactly why I was going crazy about it. And I couldn't see where it was logging (the way I was executing the commands wasn't printing out tot the console), so I was going doubly insane!

Answer (score 12):

There is nothing magical about an Amazon Linux hosted on EC2 instance. The reason everyone uses some variant of Linux is because Linux is Linux.

That said, this is how I reset MySQL `root` passwords on Ubuntu servers if I run into trouble like this. The overall concepts should work for any version of Linux with just small tweaks to handle specifics.

First, I would stop MySQL like this; this is the command I would use on Ubuntu:

```
sudo service mysql stop
```

With that done, startup MySQL again manually with the [`--skip-grant-tables`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_skip-grant-tables) option; this is considered risky for some environments since it basically launches MySQL with all grants/permissions given to everyone in the world. But it is what you need to do to fix the `root` issue:

```
sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables &
```

On some setups you might need to enter the full path to `mysqld` or `mysqld_safe` for this to work like this:

```
sudo /usr/bin/mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
```

Now with MySQL restarted with it’s grants open to the world, login like this:

```
mysql -u root mysql
```

That basically logs you in as the user `root` to the database `mysql` which manages all administrative aspects of MySQL access.

Now run this query; of course change `YOURNEWPASSWORD` to match the desired new password you want to assign to the `root` user:

```
UPDATE user SET Password=PASSWORD('YOURNEWPASSWORD') WHERE user='root'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES; exit;
```

As you can see that is a concatenated command which runs an `UPDATE`, then a `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` to reload the MYSQL grants tables and `exit` to get you out of MySQL.

With that done you should all be set and `root` should have the password reset to match whatever `YOURNEWPASSWORD` you changed it to.

Comment: It does not have a default password set. To set one you'll start mysql service then run #sudo mysql_secure_installation

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with this for a couple hours and I just found out the solution.

In my case I was trying to set a password for the `root` user.
I saw that when I ran `select * from mysql.user;` the root user had as `plugin` the value `socket`. I simply forced the change to use `mysql_native_password` plugin by running this command:

`ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' identified with mysql_native_password by 'password_goes_here'`